iCloud Mail: how to do keyword search
In iCloud Mail (web access not mail.app) I want to search and apply rules for emails with the word script in the subject though not words with script in it like subscription or prescription. I have tried using single and double quote around the keyword (including spaces either side of the keyword), and boolean operators such as NOT subscription -subscription. Any advice on how to get this to work?
